# Derivation of Formula for Steady State Conduction in Circular Section

Tags: thermodynamics

I am currently studying a chapter regarding the thermal properties of materials. Inside the lecture slides given by my lecturer, I came across an equation that I have no idea how to derive. Please help.
[image]

How could I derive the equation above from $Q=-kdT/dx$?

Answer (score 2):

Let Q be the total rate of heat flow (per unit length of cylinder) through any surface of constant r within the system.  This radial rate of heat flow does not change with r (since the heat has nowhere else to go).  The heat flux (per unit area) through the surface of constant r is given by:  $$q=-k\frac{dT}{dr}$$ So the total rate of heat flow per unit length of cylinder is given by:$$Q=-(2\pi r)k\frac{dT}{dr} $$So now all one needs to do is integrate this equation between the two boundaries.